# Not having continuous sleep in the night

Tags: toddler, infant, sleep-training

My daughter is 19 months old and does not sleep continuously at night. She wakes up twice or thrice and sits down, sometimes asking for milk. Sometimes she wakes up around 4 AM - 4:30 AM and does not sleep for the next 1 and a half hours.

We tried everything from changing the bed to adjusting the air flow in the room, changing her dinner diet still no luck.

Anyone who has encountered a similar situation. Any clue on how to deal with this situation.

Some facts:
I start putting her to sleep around 9:30 PM and she takes 20-40 mins to sleep, drinks milk before sleeping. Dinner is given around 8:30-9 PM.

Comment: What do you do when she wakes up?

Comment: Hi and Welcome! Have you read the links/questions about other families and this problem? I am not experienced with this specific problem, but there are many people who have questions like this one on site. Is there any other information that makes your situation different or confusing for you?

Comment: [LINK](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/18633/1y8m-old-daughter-wont-sleep-thru-night)  this one might help

Answer (score 1):

Children typically need about 12 hours of sleep a night at that stage give or take an hour. You should put her to sleep about 10 hours before you want to get her up. For me that means they are asleep about 9 pm. It used to be 8 pm but our life and schedule is so hectic it would be a military drill at the end of the day to get them to bed at 8. So they sleep from 9 to 7 typically. Our youngest sometimes gets up at 5:30 or 6. The only thing I can think that may get him to sleep longer is a nice calming bed time routine with lights out. If hes all excited around bed time he'll get up earlier.

Just focus on the routine, every incremental change will be like pulling teeth but she'll fall in line in a week or 2 if you show her the way. If you waver, she will see it and try to force staying up later.

If she wakes up at night, do NOT pick her up. Just pat her on the back, give her some kisses and shhhhh her back to sleep. You should try and leave the room before she actually falls asleep so she knows she doesnt need you there to sleep. That will take a little bit of time.

Like everything in parenting, its mostly the parent, not the child. We have to be the firm ones and we have to show the way.

Comment: This sounds too simple, imho.

Comment: It is pretty simple. People tend to overthink things, especially when it comes to human nature. Our bodies are used to rhythms, sunrise-sunset. Thats pretty simple!